# Navigate back to application from Gmail

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, gmail

In my application I am sending mail. To send mail, I have made Gmail as default. But on click of back navigation, I want to navigate back to my application but the inbox of Gmail is being displayed.
 Below is my code:

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ 

                  "abc.k@india.dharma.com" });    

            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 1);
            ResolveInfo best = null;

            for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm")
                        || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase()
                        .contains("gmail"))
                    best = info;
            if (best != null)
                intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName,
                        best.activityInfo.name);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            // Copy file to external storage
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            LifeUser lt = new LifeUser(getApplicationContext());
            LifeTimestamp lts = new LifeTimestamp();
            String desFile = "genReport"
                    + lts.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ".txt";
            try {
                lt.generateReportLog(desFile);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage());
            }
            // Get the Uri from the external file and add it to the
            // intent
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), desFile));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking the back button from gmail your code is irrelevant. Whatever gmail has defined to be the behavior of the back button will be executed. Once you leave gmail the next lower Activity in the stack will be called, which would probably be your Activity.

Comment: but back press is working fine for me. On back press it returns back to my application

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. I thought your intention was to navigate back to your app when pressing the back button. If that is working, what is your question?

Comment: I want to navigate back to my application on click of action bar that is also called Action Bar navigation back, represented by left arrow.